# What does a single colon introduce as part of a constructor?

Tags: c++

This is from a CPP Source File:

```
class classname{

    //constructor
    classname(anotherclass *ptr);

    private:
        string firstname;
        string lastname;

};

classname::classname(anotherclass *ptr): firstname("Nathan"), lastname("Narcovy"){

    //some other definitions

}
```

I come from C, but I do know a bit of Object Oriented Language,
But I don't understand `classname:string,string` . I only remember a colon `:` was used for inheritance.

Comment: This is surely covered within the first chapters of any decent C++ intro book.

Comment: I am not seeing any `classname:string,string`. However, this question is way too basic for this site. Stack Overflow assumes you did some research on yourself.

Comment: Any answer would be meaningless unless you had some prior knowledge on C++. And then you probably wouldn't need the answer anymore.

Comment: I assume you are referring to the initializer list of the classname constructor.

Comment: I think he is referring to to the way initial values are assigned in the constructor. Have a read: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_constructor_destructor.htm

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is this weird colon-member syntax in the constructor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711990/what-is-this-weird-colon-member-syntax-in-the-constructor)

Comment: It's not offtopic, but it should have been closed as a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711990/what-is-this-weird-colon-member-syntax-in-the-constructor as @Cubbi points out. Read that question to get your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually how the initializer list works for constructor.

I've found [this](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/101-constructor-initialization-lists/) tutorial which seems to explain it decently for newcomer.